# What are the rules with attached creepers in Cthulhu Fluxx?

Tags: fluxx

If I have a creeper attached to an investigator, does that still prevent me from winning?  I understand that having a lone creeper in front of you prevents you from winning---unless the goal says otherwise---but what if it’s attached to an investigator that is needed to win?

I know that if you attach a creeper to a keeper that removes the keepers special powers, but does it also strip the keeper of being a playable card?  I find that the Cthulhu Fluxx deck is stacked with creepers but not nearly enough cards and abilities to discard those creepers.  Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot win with a creeper out, even if it is attached to an investigator, unless that creeper is a condition of the victory (such as the Insane Nightmares goal)

See this image taken from https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvoXt.jpg for the card text:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I guess I got confused with the “unless conditions say otherwise” which I’m assuming refers to goals that contain creepers in order to win.  It would be nice if there was more cards to help fight off those pesky creepers.

Comment: Creepers are a real bane in Cthulhu Fluxx, but there are tons of goals that include creepers. I guess it's thematic at least. But there are some awesome cards in there too, like the Elder Sign.